Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{c}}g(x)f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{c}}f(x)\cdot \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow{c}}g(x)$ (the 2 limit exist)
I'm currently reading the book book of proof, and I am learning about some basic proof in Calculus. This proof on the textbook confuses me, so I am reaching out for help here.
The proof is pretty long, so I directly paste the picture here.
I tried to solve the problem by myself, and I obtained the $(A)$ inequality. But what I couldn't understand is the following step in yellow highlight. He says that by making $|x-c|$ sufficiently small, we can make the expression $|f(x)-L|$ and $|L|\cdot|g(x)-M| $ arbitarily small. But $|g(x)| $ could grow large as $|f(x)-L|$ shrinks. And then, he choose a small region $\delta$, which enforces $|g(x)-M|<1$
My quesion is, as $x\rightarrow{c}$, shouldn't $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ approach $L$ and $M$ simultaneously? Why is there to limit $|g(x)-M|<1$ as $|f(x)-L|$ goes arbitarily small? I thought that $|g(x)-M|$ be arbitarily small either. Even $g(x)$ goes large as $|f(x)-L|$ goes arbitarily small, it should approach $M$ at the same time. I don't know why is there to set up an $\delta '$ region and limit $|g(x)-M|<1$ there.


You get a $\delta$ in the definition of the first limit and another $\delta$ in the definition of the second limit. Take the minimum of the two limits to make $|f(x)-L|$ and $|g(x)-L|$ simultaneously small.

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. See here for why.

The purpose of finding such a delta so that $|g(x) - M|$ is smaller than a known/definite constant, such as $1$, is so that $|g(x)|$ will surely be bounded (because we don't know that) within that interval. We can do that because the epsilon is arbitrary in the definition of a limit. Thus, by some manipulations we get $|g(x)| < 1 + |M|$, which makes |g(x)| clearly bounded. Then, later in the proof, we can set up the "ultimate" $\delta$ to be equal to the minimum of this delta and the deltas of the other known limits $|f(x) - L|$ and $|g(x) - M|$, as detailed in the proof you showed, so that it simultaneously satisfies all the conditions, allowing us to substitute everything, and we have our proof.

The proof requires that $\lvert g(x) \rvert$ is bounded above in a neighborhood of $c$. Only then we can conclude that $\lvert f(x) - L \rvert \cdot  \lvert g(x) \rvert$ gets arbitrarily small by making $\lvert x -c \rvert$ small.
That $\lvert g(x) \rvert$ is bounded above in a neighborhood of $c$ is intuitively clear because $g(x) \to M$ as $x \to c$. Nevertheless a formal proof is needed. This is done by showing that $\lvert g(x) \rvert < \lvert M \rvert +1$ provided $\lvert x - c \rvert$ is sufficiently small. The choice of $1$ is arbitrary, one can work with any $r > 0$.

I think a simpler argument is as follows.
$$f(x)g(x)-LM=[f(x)-L][g(x)-M]+L[g(x)-M]+M[f(x)-L] $$
Then
$$|f(x)-g(x)|\le |f(x)-L|\,|g(x)-M|+|L|\,|g(x)-M|+|M|\,|f(x)-L|$$ For $0<\eta <1$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for $|x-c|<\eta$ we have $$|f(x)-L|<\eta,\quad |g(x)-M|<\eta\quad (*)$$ Then
$$|f(x)g(x)-LM|<\eta^2+(|L|+|M|)\eta<(1+|L|+|M|)\eta\quad (**)$$
Now for given  $\varepsilon>0$ let $\eta=(1+|L|+|M|+\varepsilon)^{-1}\varepsilon.$ Then $0<\eta<1.$ For such $\eta$ we choose $\delta>0$ so that $(*)$ is satisfied. Then $(**)$ implies $$|f(x)g(x)-LM|<\varepsilon$$
Observe that in this way we avoid proving the boundedness of $g(x)$ for $x$ close to $c.$
